# not able to Access files in shared dir on NFS

Tags: java, file-handling, nfs, file-sharing, fileshare

I have enabled and shared a dir through NFS on Windows server 2012.
I using Xfile library to access it but I am not able to access it.
following is the code by which I am trying to connect to NFS.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import com.sun.xfile.*;
import com.sun.nfs.*;

public class ClientPro {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

   try {
           XFile xf = new XFile("nfs://172.25.16.211//nfs//abc.txt");
           if (xf.exists())
           {    
                System.out.println("DIR or File Exist");
                if (xf.canRead())
                {    
                    System.out.println("DIR or File is Readable");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("DIR or File is Not Readable");
                }
            }else
                System.out.println("DIR or File not Exist");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

       }
 }
```

Output of above code is:
        DIR or File not Exist

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried stripping the surplus slashes? (`"nfs://172.25.16.211/nfs/abc.txt"`)

Comment: yes, about path I have tried all possible combinations still its not working